# Any scenario for using ElGamal-SIGNATURE over RSA?

Tags: rsa, signature, elgamal-signature

On a homework assignment, we're asked to give an example in which scenario one would use an ElGamal-Signature over an RSA-Signature.
I found this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/36861/55423), but the answer also only describes why RSA is superior. I searched a while now, but I don't really find any reason why one would use a Schoolbook-ElGamal (not DSA or elliptic curves) instead of RSA.

Does anyone have an additional idea?

Comment: PKCS#1 v1.5 signatures are deterministic, which is something you may not always want. RSA-PSS solves that issue though. The keys seem to be smaller if you assume that $p$ and $g$ are known in advance. Just guessing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ElGamal signature works as follows.  Define a large prime $p = 2qs + 1$ where $q$ is a prime.  Let $g$ be an element of order $q$ and a hash function $H\colon \{0,1\}^* \to \mathbb{Z}_q$. The public key is $y = g^x \bmod p$ and the private key is $x \in \mathbb{Z}_q$. The signature of a message $m$ is given by a pair $(r,s)$ where $$r=g^k \bmod p\quad\text{and}\quad s = k^{-1}(H(m) - xr) \bmod q$$
for a random integer $k \in \mathbb{Z}_q$.  The validity of a signature $(r,s)$ on message $m$ is checked by verifying that $r^sy^r \equiv g^{H(m)} \pmod p$.

It is worth to see that the two expensive operations in the signature generation, namely computing $g^k \bmod p$ and $k^{-1} \bmod q$, are independent of the message to be signed.  They can therefore be precomputed.  ElGamal signatures can be preferred when signing should be done very fast, like for example to authenticate a car at a toll bridge.  In this mode (called off-line/on-line),

1. **[off-line phase]** several coupons $(r_i, t_i)$, with $r_i = g^{k_i} \bmod p$ and $t_i = k_i^{-1} \bmod q$, for random integers $k_i \in \mathbb{Z}_q$ are pre-computed;
2. **[on-line phase]** when a message $m$ has to be signed, the signer takes a fresh coupon $(r_i, t_i)$ and computes the signature as $r = r_i$ and $s = t_i(H(m) - xr_i) \bmod q$.

*Notes.*

1. A coupon can only be used once.  Each signature needs a *fresh* coupon.
2. In the on-line phase, the cost of an ElGamal signature is only a couple of multiplications modulo $q$ (which is much faster than a full modular exponentiation in the case of RSA).

Comment: Precompution and time-memory-tradeoff... You're absolutely right, thank you (and +1) for leading me to my blind spot.